# When closing RDP (X button) after 1 minute it closes All Applications

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

winserver 2008

When i press X on the RDP after 1 minute all the programs i had open, are closed,
it's like the server logged off..

how do i disable it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your [timeouts for Disconnected Sessions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

Open gpedit.msc

Browse to Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Remote Desktop Services --> Remote Desktop Session Host --> Session Time Limits.

Enable the "Set time limit for disconnected sessions" and set it to Never

and change the Local Security Policy under Local Policies->Security Options-> Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+Del" to Enabled, the problem dissapears.

Comment: How do I do the second part?

Comment: For the second part Goto Administrative tools -> Local Security Policies. Sorry for the delayed response. hope it helped you.