# Keep AWS EC2 Windows server terminal app alive after disconnection

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm running a terminal app on my AWS windows server and use RDP(Remote desktop) to connect to the server

but the app will stop running after I disconnect RDP for a while (about 10 minutes or more)

how to keep this terminal app running after I disconnect my RDP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519425/when-closing-rdp-x-button-after-1-minute-it-closes-all-applications/16414585#16414585
Can you try this